# OCaml Parsing a list

Tags: list, parsing, ocaml, lexical-analysis, cons

I would like to parse  "[a;b;c;d;e;f;g]" as "a::b::c::d::e::f::g::[]"
In my part of my parser I have

```
listOps:
   | combOps COLONCOLON listOps { Bin($1,Cons,$3) }
   | combOps SEMI listOps       { Bin($1,Cons,$3) }
   | combOps                    { $1 }
;
```

and I have this further down.

```
   | LBRAC RBRAC                { NilExpr }
   | LBRAC listOps RBRAC        { $2 }
```

But I'm not sure how to get it to read the list between the "[" and "]" as having a "::[]" at the end of it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your grammar as given doesn't look quite right to me. In essence it treats `::` and `;` identically. So it would treat `[a::b]` and `[a;b]` as the same. If you figure out how to handle the two cases differently, you'll probably find a place handle the `[]` at the end of a list specified with `::`.

As a side comment, if you allow `a :: b :: []` you are allowing the right side of `::` to be a non-empty list. So you might want `a :: [b]` to be allowed, as it is in OCaml. Or maybe you'd rather not, it's your grammar!